# Python parse text file into nested dictionaries

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary

Consider the following data structure:

```
[HEADER1]
{
   key value
   key value
   ...
   [HEADER2]
   {
      key value
      ...
   }
   key value
   [HEADER3]
   {
      key value
      [HEADER4]
      {
         key value
         ...
      }
   }
   key value
}
```

There are no indents in the raw data, but I added them here for clarity. The number of key-value pairs is unknown, '...' indicates there could be many more
within each [HEADER] block. Also the amount of [HEADER] blocks is unknown.

Note that the structure is nested, so in this example header 2 and 3 are inside header 1 and header 4 is inside header 3.

There can be many more (nested) headers, but I kept the example short.

How do I go about parsing this into a nested dictionary structure? Each [HEADER] should be the key to whatever follows inside the curly brackets.

The final result should be something like:

```
dict = {'HEADER1': 'contents of 1'}
contents of 1 = {'key': 'value', 'key': 'value', 'HEADER2': 'contents of 2', etc}
```

I'm guessing I need some sort of recursive function, but I am pretty new to Python and have no idea where to start.

For starters, I can pull out all the [HEADER] keys as follows:

```
path = 'mydatafile.txt'
keys = []

with open (path, 'rt') as file:
   for line in file:
      if line.startswith('['):
         keys.append(line.rstrip('\n'))

for key in keys:
   print(key)
```

But then what, maybe this not even needed?

Any suggestions?

Comment: So are there really headers without closing `}`s and also double `}`s and values outside of `{}`s?

Comment: No, each header is followed by {...}, but since they can be nested, there could be two closing brackets on adjacent lines.

Comment: What's going on with stuff under header2 and 4 then?

Comment: Oh wait, is header 2 within header1 ? Might be an idea to show how you'd expect the output `dict` to actually look

Comment: Correct, and 4 is inside 3, and 3 is inside 1.

Comment: @Koen. You **really** need to make it clearer in your question that the headers/sections can be nested.

Comment: @Koen. PS: could this be some kind of standard format? Where are you getting these files from?

Comment: Gotcha, I updated the question.  The data comes from analytical software, and I am stuck with that format. No idea if this is some sort of standard format.

Comment: Also there are no indents in the input file, which probably caused the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by pre-formatting your file content using few regex and then pass it to `json.loads`

You can do these kind of regex substitutions one by one:

**#1** [`\[(\w*)\]\n`](https://regex101.com/r/IK8hwl/2) -> `"$1":`

**#2** [`\}\n(\w)`](https://regex101.com/r/wRT2tr/1) -> `},$1`

**#3** [`(\w*)\s(\w*)\n([^}])`](https://regex101.com/r/qpplZC/3) -> `$1:$2,$3`

**#4** [`(\w*)\s(\w*)\n\}`](https://regex101.com/r/ukbysd/1) -> `$1:$2}`

and then finally pass the final string to `json.loads`:

```
import json
d = json.loads(s)
```

which will parse it to a dict format.

**Explanation :**

**1.** `\[(\w*)\]\n` : replace `[HEADERS]\n` with `"HEADERS":`

**2.** `\}\n(\w)`: replace any closing braces i.e, `}` that have any value after them, with `},`

**3.** `(\w*)\s(\w*)\n([^}])`: replace `key value\n` with `key:value,` for lines having any next elements

**4.** `(\w*)\s(\w*)\n\}`: replace `key value\n` with `key:value` for lines having no next elements

So, by minor modifications to these regexes you will be able to parse it to a dict format, the basic concept is to reformat the file contents to a format that can be parsed easily.

Comment: So how do I iterate over the lines and accomplish this? `for line in file: line = re.sub("\[(\w*)\]\n", "", line)` is not changing anything?

Comment: don't iterate over lines, read the whole file and then use these regex on the file content and then pass the resulting string to the next regex

Comment: I see, I tried that: `s = open(path, 'rt').read() s1 = re.sub("\[(\w*)\]\n", "", s)`, but no changes.

Comment: also don't replace with empty string, check the answer for what to substitute with which regex. see this for how to use captured groups : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711567/how-to-use-python-regex-to-replace-using-captured-group

Comment: if your file content has a format inconsistent with that mentioned in the question, obv this regex won't work you'll have to do some minor tweaks a/c to your needs to make it work. I suspect, that might be the case.

Comment: I'm using a test file exactly as above, I guess I'm having trouble with the syntax; this: `s1 = re.sub('\[(\w*)\]\n', '"$1":', s)` will replace `[HEADER1]` with `"$1":`

Comment: checkout the above link, that'll help a lot with substitution, basically you need to use `\1` instead of `$1` in python

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157202/discussion-between-koen-and-ashish-ranjan).