# Python recursive function called too many times

Tags: python, parsing, dictionary, nested

This is a follow-up to this question: [Python parse text file into nested dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46866327/python-parse-text-file-into-nested-dictionaries)

I initially accepted the answer which suggested to format the input with regexes, but after looking closer at the input, there are still some problems that I cannot can process with the proposed regexes.

So I am back at recursively parsing the lines into a dictionary.

What I have so far is:

```
def parseToDictionary(input):
    key = ''
    value = ''
    result = {}

    if input[0].startswith('{'): # remove {
        del input[0]

    result.clear() # clear the dict for each recursion

    for idx, line in enumerate(input):
        line = line.rstrip() # remove trailing returns

        if line.startswith('['):
            key = line
            value = parseToDictionary(input[idx+1:]) # parse the next level
        elif line.startswith('}'): # reached the end of a block
            return result
        else:
            elements = line.split('\t')
            key = elements[0]
            if len(elements) > 1:
                value = elements[1]
            else:
                value = 'Not defined' # some keys may not have a value, so set a generic value here
        if key:
            result[key] = value

    return result
```

Here is an example (very simplified!) input:

```
[HEADER1]
{
key1    value
key2    long value, with a comma
[HEADER2]
{
key 1234
emptykey
}
}
```

The output is:

```
'[HEADER2]': 
{
    'emptykey': 'Not defined', 
    'key': '1234'
}, 
'key2': 'long value, with a comma', 
'key1': 'value', 
'[HEADER1]': 
{
    'emptykey': 'Not defined', 
    'key2': 'long value, with a comma', 
    'key1': 'value', 
    'key': '1234', 
    '[HEADER2]': 
    {
        'emptykey': 'Not defined', 
        'key': '1234'
    }
 }, 
 'emptykey': 'Not defined', 
 'key': '1234'
 }
```

But it should be:

```
'[HEADER1]': 
{
    'key1': 'value', 
    'key2': 'long value, with a comma', 
    '[HEADER2]': 
    {
        'emptykey': 'Not defined', 
        'key': '1234'
    }
 }
```

So each line that starts with an `[` is the key for the next block. Inside each blocks are multiple key-value pairs, and there could also be another nested level. What goes wrong is that some blocks are parsed multiple times, and I cannot figure out where it goes wrong.

The input parameter is `mydatafile.split('\n')`

Who can help me out?

Comment: What is `input`?  Is it a list of tokens?

Comment: I have added that to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to skip the lines, that are processsed in the subsections:

```
def parse_to_dictionary(lines):
    def parse_block(lines):
        contents = {}
        if next(lines).strip() != '{':
            raise AssertionError("'{' expected")
        for line in lines:
            line = line.strip()
            if line == '}':
                return contents
            elif line[0] == '[':
                contents[line] = parse_block(lines)
            else:
                parts = line.split('\t', 1)
                contents[parts[0]] = None if len(parts) == 1 else parts[1]

    lines = iter(lines)
    key = next(lines)                
    if key[0] != '[':
        raise AssertionError("format error")
    return {key: parse_block(lines)}
```

Comment: Since the first line is not `{`, i will fail immediately. What I really try to do is just to skip the lines with `{`.

Comment: So to fix that, I commented out the `raise AssertionError("'{' expected")` line and indented the for-loop. Works perfect now.

Comment: Disregard these comments, there was an error in my input file.