# How to remove characters from the string?

Tags: python, regex

How to remove the characters from the column which consists of digits and characters?

This is the dataset:

```
Name
0yrs 0mon
11yrs 11mon 
2yrs 2mon
3yrs 5mon
```

This is the expected output:

```
Name
0.0
11.11
2.2
3.5
```

This is the actual output:

```
Name
0.0.
11.11.
2.2.
3.5.
```

I tried by using the command

```
df.Name = df.Name.str.replace('\D+','.')
```

Comment: Why does the second row become 1.11 rather than 11.11?

Comment: Sorry for the typo error. I should have written 11.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try chaining [`rstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html) to the end of what you already tried and that should strip out the trailing period:

```
In [5] df.Name.str.replace('\D+', '.').str.rstrip('.')
Out[5]: 
0      0.0
1    11.11
2      2.2
3      3.5
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Comment: Good idea. For that matter, you could just do `[:-1]` to cut off the last character, too.

Comment: @StardustGogeta - although it's not explicitly mentioned in the question, my understanding is that `df` is a Pandas DataFrame, so `[:-1]` wouldn't work.

Comment: I am actually not familiar with Pandas, so I wouldn't know anything about that, but thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

I see two trivial ways of doing this with a second pass.  One is to simply remove the trailing period.  The other is to replace the letter strings separately: a dot if it's separated by a space; remove it otherwise.

```
df.Name = df.Name.str.replace('\D+ ','.')
df.Name = df.Name.str.replace('\
```

D+','')

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
regex = re.compile(r"(\d+)\w+ (\d+)\w+")
df.Name = regex.sub(r"\1.\2", df.Name.str)
```

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711567/how-to-use-python-regex-to-replace-using-captured-group) explains the replacement with capturing groups from the regex. The `\d+` matches the numbers and the `\w+` matches the remaining Unicode word characters immediately afterwards.

Comment: Yes, i made some similar: ``>>> re.sub('[a-z]{3}\s','.', '11yrs 11mon', 1)
'11.11mon'
>>> re.sub('[a-z]{3}','', '11.11mon', 1)
'11.11'
>>> 
``